# Modifying golang Docker Container using the running shell

Tags: go, docker, google-compute-engine

I'm using Docker to deploy my web service to Google Compute Engine and I'm following the instructions given here: https://blog.golang.org/docker

I want to install ffmpeg in the golang container and my approach is to get access to the shell as

docker run -t -i my-webservice /bin/bash

In contrary to the ubuntu:14.04 image, I don't get access to the bash shell. How can that be?

I have also found an image, where the ffmpeg is already configured and installed (https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/cellofellow/ffmpeg/). Is it possible to get access to the container from the golang container or do I have to install ffmpeg into my own docker image?

Comment: Did you try `/bin/sh`? Bash is not a must on Linux. There might be other shell installed, probably dash.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. I have tried csh, tcsh, ksh, sh (assumed installed in /bin)

Comment: Although you probably should be incorporating the ffmpeg installation as much as possible into the Dockerfile, if you really need access to the container use `docker-enter` from the `nsenter` package. Install using `docker run --rm -v /usr/local/bin:/target jpetazzo/nsenter`. See https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter for more info.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to install ffmpeg to your golang container by adding a `RUN` to your Dockerfile, like

`RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg`

The words *modifying*, *Docker Container*, *running shell*, kind of contradicts the meaning of Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Installing ffmepeg is not as simple if additional codecs need to be installed as well, being the reason that I would like to play around using the shell before writing the docker script (copying the Docker script from cellofellow/ffmpeg works).

An answer to the problems are described here: https://github.com/docker-library/golang/issues/27